# Sysprep RegDeleteKey Failed

Tags: sysprep, windows-8.1

Trying to sysprep a Windows 8.1 system and getting a fatal error.

When I check setuperr.log It seems to be failing at `Sysprep_Generalize_MountPointManager: RegDeleteKey Failed with error=2`.

From looking around I am guessing it cant find a registry key, anyone know how to find which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find how to see the exact regKey that was failing, but running CCleaner registry cleanup on the system and restarting seemed to fix the issue.